# Does Google Maps respect the <BalloonStyle> definition in KML?

Tags: google-maps, kml

I'm using the GGeoXml object to overlay KML on an embedded Google Map. I need to customize the popup balloon for placemarks, so I'm trying to use the [`<BalloonStyle>`](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#balloonstyle) element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0">
    <name>Concessions</name>
    <Style id="masterPolyStyle">
        ...
        <BalloonStyle>
            <text>
                <![CDATA[
                  <h6>Concession</h6>
                  <h4>$[name]</h4>
                  <p>$[description]</p>
                ]]>
            </text>
            <displayMode>default</displayMode>
            <bgColor>DDA39B81</bgColor>
        </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>

    ...

</Document>
```

This works as expected in Google Earth, but the embedded map API appears to ignore this altogether. I suppose I could just leave out the `<name>` element altogether and just put everything in HTML inside the `<description>` element, but I'd like to be able to take advantage of the [`<ExtendedData>`](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#extendeddata) element to display custom data in a structured way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, like you have mentioned, html in the description is the only way I know that you can control the style of balloons through kml/georss feed.

Answer (score 2):

This is now documented here (2009/04):

http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps.html

- < BalloonStyle > no

(When did you ask this ? This forum/service needs a big fat DATE on each question, with a year in it :-) )

2$c,
*pike

Comment: Thanks for the update. If you hover over the date in my signature above, you can get the full date and time of the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the document referenced above (http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps.html) must have changed, b/c now it says:

> <BalloonStyle>  partially   only <text>
>   is supported

My problem is that the <text> seems to work for one KML file, but not another. The one that works for has polygon placemarkers, the other has points represented by icons - I wonder if that is why...